# Simple "SELECT" with variable but without "INTO"

Tags: sql, database, oracle, plsql

I have some different SELECT queries with same values. I want to use something like DECLARE but when I write a simple DECLARE it says that "INTO" is expected.

If I want only a "SELECT", how can I use this form witout "INTO"?

Simply I have two (or more) selects:

```
SELECT * FROM my_table1 WHERE column1=5 and column2=6;
```

and

```
SELECT * FROM my_table2 WHERE col1=5 and col2=6;
```

Now I want to declare a variable like var_col1 and var_col2 and use them in both select queries at the same time.

I thought this would work:

```
DECLARE
var_col1 number := 5;
var_vol2 number := 6;
BEGIN
SELECT * FROM my_table1 WHERE column1=var_col1 and column2=var_col2;
SELECT * FROM my_table2 WHERE col1=var_col1 and col2=var_col1;
/* and more SELECTs with var_col1 and var_col2 */
END;
```

But no chance... How is the way to do that without a procedure or function?

Comment: Which SQL client are you using?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

When you write `select * from some_table;` in SQL*Plus, `SQL*Plus` is acting as the client program, and does a lot of work for you, under the covers, in terms of the data being returned from the database, formatting it and displaying it.

As soon as you type `DECLARE`, you begin a PL/SQL block.  Now, You're calling PL/SQL, and PL/SQL is calling SQL.  As a result, you need to decide how to handle the data being returned from the SQL, in PL/SQL.  The way to do that, is via an `INTO` clause and a variable to receive the output.  Considering that, where would the output data from the `SELECT` go, if you don't provide an `INTO` clause?  It has to go somewhere, right?

Hope that's clear.

Comment: What's wrong with the value going **back to the client** exactly as if you had done the select without a `declare` block?

Comment: Yes, we want to discard all the data without a dummy INTO to receive it so that we can cause the side-effects of running a SELECT query to happen, but not use the data at all.  I'm sad that this doesn't answer the question.

Comment: Not sure what to tell you....sorry you're sad that Oracle doesn't actually work like you wish it did....If you re-read my reply, I think it's pretty clear why INTO is required when running a PL/SQL block.

Answer (score 1):

You have to select into your declared variables if you want to do it that way or set the columns.  For example:

```
DECLARE
var_col1 number := 5;
var_vol2 number := 6;
BEGIN
   SELECT my_table1.var_col into var_col1 
     FROM my_table1 
    WHERE column1=var_col1 
      AND column2=var_col2;
--etc.....
END;
```

OR

```
DECLARE
    var_col1 number := 5;
    var_vol2 number := 6;
    BEGIN
       SELECT 5 into var_col1 
         FROM my_table1 
        WHERE column1=var_col1 
          AND column2=var_col2;
    --etc.....
    END;
```

EDIT: I should also add that you can also declare output Vvariables that you can use in SQL to return output to help with debugging etc.  So you can do something like:

```
DECLARE
 out  varchar2(200);
```

And in your BEGIN statement do something like:

```
 dbms_output.put_line(out);
```

Which outputs some potential useful info (depending what you set out to).

Comment: But I want to select all columns?

Comment: And I don't get, what is the purpose of "into" really? What does that mean for a DECLARE?

Comment: Then the answer you want is @Edurado Ivanec's solution.  Where you set the value in the BEGIN clause

Comment: To answer your question about the INTO, please read @Mark J. Bobak response.

Comment: @YasinOkumus - It depends on how you're using it.  In the case above it's copying values from a table into a variable.

Answer (score 1):

You're using PLSQL Developer, which has a choice of many different window types.  If I recall correctly, the Command window is the one which is a SQL*Plus emulator.  That being so this should work:

```
var n1 number 
var n2 number 

exec &&n1 := 5
exec &&n2 := 6

SELECT * FROM my_table1 WHERE column1=&&n1 and column2=&&n2 ; 
SELECT * FROM my_table2 WHERE col1&&n1 and col2=&&n2;
```

In other words, define two substitution variables, assign values to them and finally deploy them in all your queries.

Comment: Very interestingly "var" is a keyword. But Pl/Sql Developer doesn't accept this all statement. So this code doesn't work. By the way, I can't find proper usage of "var" for plsql...

Comment: @YasinOkumus: `var` is *not* PL/SQL, it's a PL/SQL Developer feature. You need to look it up in the PL/SQL developer manual

Comment: Thank you, I meant PL/SQL Developer.